# random even number in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, random

I know that :

```
randNum = arc4random_uniform(N);
```

Will set randNum to a random number from 0 to N - 1.

However how can I modify the above statement to get a random even number from 0 to N - 1?

Comment: `randNum = 2 * arc4random_uniform(N / 2);`

Comment: And off the lowest bit every time after you get the random number.

Answer (score 1):

*@user3477950* has given you the correct answer.

While it is common practice to use the modulus as a way of trimming down limits, e.g.: `randEvenNum = 2*(arc4random_uniform(N) % (N/2))`, this is not safe for arbitrary moduli as it biases the random number probability density. It is thus better to do as *@user3477950* suggests, and use the function to generate a uniform distribution over half of your space, and then double the amplitude (an operation that has no effect on probability density)

As an example, imagine you have a generator that produces an even distribution between 0-5 inclusive. You want one that does 0-3 inclusive so you say, hey, lets mod by 3+1 and we will have our generator. The problem with this, is that if the density of your generator is 1/6 for all numbers 0-5 originally, then when you take this modulus,

> {0,4} -> 0
>
> {1,5} -> 1
>
> {2} -> 2
>
> {3} -> 3

The probability density is no longer flat. We had:

```
{1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6}
```

And we now have

```
{1/3, 1/3, 1/6, 1/6}
```

When what we wanted was

```
{1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4}
```

The `arc4random()` function is an RSA produced algorithm and is quite high in entropy. More detailed results would require analysis. However, assuming that the function produces a highly uniform density between 0 and N-1 then the best answer to your question is:

```
randEvenNum = 2*arc4random_uniform(N/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is faster using bitwise operator, clear the lowest bit as @Gallymon said.

`unsigned int evenNumber = arc4random_uniform(N) & 0xFFFFFFFE ;`